# How to chain nohup commands to run in succession?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh, nohup

I would like to run a bunch of nohup commands in succession and store the output in different files.

I came up with this:

```
$ nohup python3 foo.py 0 &> nohup-0-foo.out && \
nohup python3 foo.py 1 &> nohup-1-foo.out && \
nohup python3 foo.py 2 &> nohup-2-foo.out && \
nohup python3 foo.py 3 &> nohup-3-foo.out && \
nohup python3 foo.py 4 &> nohup-4-foo.out &
```

But this seems not to work (`python3 foo.py 0` is executed, but it stop after this).

Q: How can I make the commands run in succession?

Comment: What is the exit status of `python3 foo.py 0`?

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways.

One, throw them all in a file -

```
$: cat script
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..4}; do python3 foo.py $i &> $i.out || break; done
```

And run that.

```
nohup ./script > script.out &
```

Two, if you just *want* to to it on the command line:

```
{ trap '' HUP; for i in {0..4}; do python3 foo.py $i &> 0.out || break; done; } &
```

or

```
{ trap '' HUP; 
  python3 foo.py 0 &> 0.out &&
  python3 foo.py 1 &> 1.out &&
  python3 foo.py 2 &> 2.out &&
  python3 foo.py 3 &> 3.out &&
  python3 foo.py 4 &> 4.out &  # why running *this one* in background?
}
```

*Basically* what `nohup` does is trap hangup signals and make sure you have all your output logged, so there should be little difference.